# Как подобрать селектор с атрибутом в котором содержится переменная?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Подскажите как подобрать селектор с атрибутом, в котором содержится переменная?
Например, есть поле **input** с атрибутом **name**. Значение поля **name** `value: "inspDate" + singlInspTime[j].id`. Его вид на html-странице будет: `name="inspDate1283"`.

Надо создать селектор вида: `$('input[name="и_что_здесь_будет_с_учетом_переменной_которую_нельзя_взять_в_кавычки???"]').val();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не это ищите?

```
$('input[name="inspDate' + singlInspTime[j].id + '"]').val();
```

Как пример:

```js
var test = 666;
var value = $('input[name="inspDate' + test + '"]').val();
console.log(value);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input name="inspDate666" value="value666" />
<input name="inspDate999" value="value999" />
```

Comment: похоже, но это не работает - вторая квадратная скобка не обернута в кавычки...

Comment: @PrinceOFF wat? присмотритесь-ка еще раз)) Добавил даже сниппет для пущей верности

Comment: Да, похоже, что это то, что надо, спасбо!